# Deploying a container to azure app service shows "No memory left on device"

Tags: linux, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have an application deployed to Azure App Service(Linux) through containers, and i have set up a CI/CD to update the containers whenever there is a code change. It was working fine until now, where i am getting ***No memory left on device*** when trying to delpoy a newer container.

I think there are some old containers and old images are residing on the device, how can i make sure that they are cleaned off every time I deploy a new container to the App Service.

Comment: Could you please help me what source are you using for CI/CD pipeline(ACR/Docker).
Also I would suggest to scale up your plan to higher tier to disable the restrictions with app service plans.

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT: I am using Docker, if i scaled up teh pan once and it pretty well ran for some days and the problem again started, as there may be some old images getting stored into and irrespective of the size of the plan, this would be filled one day. Apart form this i am using the Continuous Deployment option from the Deployment Center's Settings section to delpoy these images onto my App Service.

Comment: The first time you run a custom Docker image in App Service, App Service does a docker pull and pulls all image layers.
 These layers are stored on disk, like if you were using Docker on-premises. 
Each time the app restarts, App Service does a docker pull, but only pulls layers that have changed. 
If there have been no changes, App Service uses existing layers on the local disk.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows#how-container-images-are-stored

Comment: while that temp space is used for those docker operations (unpacking/writing operations that require a temporary directory), 
it's also used for your application logs as well.
https://puneet-gupta.github.io/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/

while creating the docker containers suggest you to use tags which identifies the version.

here we have a list of base images that are cached in Azure App Service for Windows Containers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows

Comment: Thanks @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT, yeah if that is the case upgrading the ASP will help, i have to then manually sometimes delete the temp memory out there for these deployments to go on smooth.